# Suppress Rsyslog to terminal

Tags: debian, logs, syslog, rsyslog

When I use Rsyslog (in bash using `logger` and in Node using `winston-syslog`), all log levels are also shown on the terminal window.

I only want to log these events, and silent the output unless they are error and above log levels.

What configuration do I need to edit to do this?